# how to convert string to time in python

Tags: python

I have (9:00:00.000) as a string. I want to convert it to actual time. In format of hh:mm:ss.miliseconds.
I think I have to use 'datetime' package but I don't know how. 
I have strtempTime = '9:00:00.000' in code.

Comment: Have you checked out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime/466376#466376

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime). You should also read python documentation on [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.strptime) built-in module

Comment: it adds date even when there is no date in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use

```
import datetime

result = datetime.datetime.strptime(strtempTime, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()
print(result, type(result))
```

Comment: ValueError: unconverted data remains: 000

Comment: I tried the code below but it's converting it to date and time. temptime=datetime.strptime(temptime,'%H:%M:%S.%f.%f'[:-3])
print("temptime:",temptime)

Comment: datetime.datetime.strptime(strtempTime, '%H:%M:%S.%f').time()

Answer (score 0):

you should use the function "strptime" from the datetime module.
it should be something like that :

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.strptime("09:00:00.000", "%H:%M:%S.%f"))
```

Check documentation for more informations : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: I tried the code below but it's converting it to date and time. temptime=datetime.strptime(temptime,'%H:%M:%S.%f.%f'[:-3]) print("temptime:",temptime)

Comment: yes, datetime format contains the date as well, but there is no problem.
If you need to use the date somewhere in your code, you can use the function "strtime" which will convert your datetime objet to string. Your datetime object will be someting like that :

    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("09:01:02.518", "%H:%M:%S.%f"), and in order to get the time as string you may use : 

    print(datetime.strftime(datetime_obj, "%H:%M:%S.%f"))